# AWS ECS: Is there simply no way to enable execution command on a stand-alone task on the AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

As the question explains itself, I need to enable execution command on a stand-alone task in AWS ECS.

I have found no information throughout the web about how to enable it by clicking my way through the AWS console.

Do I have to run the `aws ecs run-task --enable-execute-command ...` command to start a task if I need enable-execute-command?

It just appear silly to me that AWS would not allow users to do it over the Console.

Why would AWS hide it on the Console? Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS didn't "hide" it in the web console, they just didn't build that feature into the web UI yet. There are lots of features missing from the ECS web console.